# Print out Fonts from the Google Font API

Tags: fonts, printing, coding-style, google-font-api

I'm using the google font api, and now I'm trying to create a print.css file.

I'm trying to get the fonts to print out but I'm not having any luck.

Does anyone know of a way to have fonts from the google font api print out?

thanks

Comment: Hi Adam. Are talking about getting the font to actually print out to a printer or output to a monitor?

Comment: print to printer. Not sure if this is just a firefox issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363664/printout-webpage-with-font-face

Comment: Yikes. Did not realize that. Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in [firefox](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/761014). Please try with other browsers. Also if your web is having a separate print specific CSS file, please ensure the font is properly embedded in that CSS too.