# printout webpage with @font-face

Tags: css, printing, font-face, custom-font

I'm using @font-face on a couple of site's I'm working on, now I'm working on styling how the pages print.

How can I implement @font-face and allow the custom fonts to appear when printing the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a **bug** issue in Firefox:

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/761014

And possibly in Chrome and Safari as well:

http://samiam.org/blog/20110606.html